# Jetpack compose infinity scroll listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, infinite-scroll, lazycolumn

I want to implement infinite scroll via LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose without any library. In other words I need a listener to be invoked when the user scrolls to the end.

Comment: What do you wish to do when user scrolls to the end? Scroll to first item as a circular list or fetch new items as paging?

Comment: @Thracian fetching new items as paging.

Answer (score 2):

I used this solution:

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun LazyListState.scrollEndCallback(crossinline callback: () -> Unit) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = this) {
        snapshotFlow { layoutInfo }
            .filter { it.totalItemsCount > 0 }
            .map { it.totalItemsCount == (it.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: -1).inc() }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .filter { it }
            .onEach { callback() }
            .collect()
    }
}
```

Its usage:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Example() {
    LazyColumn(
        state = rememberLazyListState().also {
            it.scrollEndCallback {
                // do sth
            }
        },
    ) {
        // items ....
    }
}
```

Also it can be reused with `LazyGridState`

Comment: Good solution, upvoted, but it has 2 problems. First one it calls data initially which might not be a problem in most cases but second one is if total height of items are smaller than height of LazyColumn it never gets called

Comment: @Thracian Thanks a lot. I've added a filter to fix initial call. But I couldn't produce second note. It works fine when I tried with 2 small items  for each page and the callback invoked sequentially to fill screen.

Comment: For second one fill LazyColumn with 3 or 5 items that fit LazyColumn when it has fullscreen height, bigger than sum of height of items initially, if there is nothing to scroll, no items out of Viewport, as i see this function never gets called. Also there might be another check you need to do when callback is being invoked. Let's say user scrolled up and down while you fetch data it will start fetching another data and it might cause second call to be invoked first if second request finishes before first one